# Getting error when run my first appium test

Tags: java, android, eclipse, appium

I am getting error in the eclipse when I run my first test in the eclipse using appium.

Following is my code:

```
package Appium;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.File;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

//import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;



public class Appium {


        WebDriver driver;

        @BeforeClass
        public void Appium() throws MalformedURLException{
            //Set up desired capabilities and pass the Android app-activity and app-package to Appium
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();


            capabilities.setCapability("BROWSER_NAME", "Chrome");
            capabilities.setCapability("VERSION", "5.1"); 
            capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","Nexus 5");
            capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");


           capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.calculator2");
        // This package name of your app (you can get it from apk info app)
            capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.android.calculator2.Calculator"); // This is Launcher activity of your app (you can get it from apk info app)
        //Create RemoteWebDriver instance and connect to the Appium server
         //It will launch the Calculator App in Android Device using the configurations specified in Desired Capabilities
           driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        }

        @Test
        public void testCal() throws Exception {
           //locate the Text on the calculator by using By.name()
           WebElement two=driver.findElement(By.name("2"));
           two.click();
           WebElement plus=driver.findElement(By.name("+"));
           plus.click();
           WebElement four=driver.findElement(By.name("4"));
           four.click();
           WebElement equalTo=driver.findElement(By.name("="));
           equalTo.click();
           //locate the edit box of the calculator by using By.tagName()
           WebElement results=driver.findElement(By.tagName("EditText"));
            //Check the calculated value on the edit box
        assert results.getText().equals("6"):"Actual value is : "+results.getText()+" did not match with expected value: 6";

        }

        @AfterClass
        public void teardown(){
            //close the app
            driver.quit();
        }

    }
```

When I run this code using testNg,I am getting following error.

> FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass Appium
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.logging.profiler.HttpProfilerLogEntry.constructMessage(HttpProfilerLogEntry.java:36)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.logging.profiler.HttpProfilerLogEntry.(HttpProfilerLogEntry.java:28)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:133)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:568)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:242)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:155)
>     at Appium.Appium.Appium(Appium.java:47)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've imported all the external jar packages properly in your project

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in above answer, you may be missing [google-gson](https://github.com/google/gson) jar in your project. 
You will find the maven dependency on same page.